# How to fix/trouble shoot the missing response from nodejs service?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to trouble shoot/fix my nodejs upload image api:

My service is being stuck at somewhere.

[image]

[image]

[image]

My service is too simple, just uploading the image by resizing through sharp api in a directory and return the full path of that file.

When I select some image at first time then everything works fine and image upload successfully with a response

but When I try to crop that image after clicking on the image and try to save it (at second time) then nodejs service return following response.

I don't why it is being happened, I tried to debug the service code and It didn't stop at anywhere. Flow has been passed/executed successfully, I didn't catch any exception/error in code.

What can be the issue in it because it still displaying

```
> Blockquote failed to load response data. no resource with given identifier found
```

Problem area is in the code of `onSaveImage` when a server side call is being served/requested. I am using the plugin for image cropping is react-easy-crop. Browser is getting refresh/reload at this line of code

```
 const jsonRes = await responseMain.json();
```

I am sharing my nodejs service code as well as reactjs code. please look into it.
Thank you.

```
-----------------package.json of nodejs
{
    "name": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-validator": "^6.12.0",
        "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mysql": "^2.18.1",
        "nodemailer": "^6.6.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
        "sharp": "^0.29.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {},
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon --inspect index.js",
        "debug": "node --nolazy --inspect-brk=9229 index.js"
    },
    "license": "ISC"
}

------ index.js---------------------------NodeJs
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
var fs = require("fs");
const fsp = fs.promises;
var path = require("path");
const sharp = require("sharp");

var $pathContentBuilder = path.join(__dirname, "../", "/public/roughdata/uploads/"); 
var $urlpathContentBuilder = "/roughdata/uploads/"; // URL path
app.use(express.json({ limit: "20mb" }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
);
function processImage(image, metadata, filename, isResizeAllow) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (isResizeAllow && isResizeAllow === true) {
            // 0.8 MB
            return image
                .resize({
                    width: Math.round(metadata.width / 2),
                    height: Math.round(metadata.height / 2),
                    fit: "cover",
                })
                .toBuffer((err, buf) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Error occured ", err);
                        return reject(err);
                    } else {
                        return resolve(buf.toString("base64"));
                    }
                });
        } else {
            return image.toBuffer((err, buf) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error occured ", err);
                    return reject(err);
                } else {
                    return resolve(buf.toString("base64"));
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

app.post("/uploaddetail", async (req, res, next) => {
    const base64Data = req.body.image;
    const filename = req.body.filename;
    let imageResizeResult = "";
    try {
        var inputbuf = Buffer.from(base64Data, "base64"); // Ta-da
        const image = await sharp(inputbuf);
        let metadata = await image.metadata();
        let convertedbase64Data = "";       
        convertedbase64Data = await processImage(image, metadata, filename, false);       
        await fsp.writeFile($pathContentBuilder + filename, convertedbase64Data, "base64");
        let resultResponse = JSON.stringify({
            success: true,
            fullurl: `${$urlpathContentBuilder}${filename}`,
            url: `${filename}`,
            imagename: `${filename}`,
            serverpath: `${$urlpathContentBuilder}`,
        });
        //res.type("json");
        res.status(200).json(resultResponse);
        //res.end();
        //next();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        const error = new HttpError(e, 404);
        return next(error);       
    }
});
```

and following is my reactjs code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { withRouter, useParams, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Page from "./Page";
import TitleBar from "./TitleBar";
import SingleGalleryRow from "./SingleGalleryRow";
import CenteredPopup from "../common/CenteredPopup";
import { MdDelete, MdOutlineCrop, MdOutlineCircle } from "react-icons/md";
import Cropper from "react-easy-crop";

import getCroppedImg from "../shared/util/cropImage";
import b64toBlob from "../shared/util/blobToImage";

function EditImage({ breadcrumb, pageName, setLoader, showToast }) {
    const [list, setList] = useState([]);
    const history = useHistory();    
    const [umodalShow, setUModalShow] = useState(false);
    const [row, setRow] = useState({
        ImageName: "",
        ImageServerPath: "",
        ImageFullUrl: "",
        ImageUrl: "",
        SiteId: 1,
        CreatedBy: 1,
        CreatedOn: "",
        Id: 0,
        Name: "",
        IsDeleted: 0,
        IsVisible: 1,
        ModifiedBy: 1,
        ModifiedOn: "",
    });
    const [isSubmitClicked, setIsSubmitClicked] = useState(false);
    const [IsDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(false);
    const [nameError, setNameError] = useState("");
    const [validated, setValidated] = useState(0);
    const [ImageName, setImageName] = useState("");
    const [base64SelectedImage, setBase64SelectedImage] = useState("");
    const { id } = useParams();
    let content = "";
    const [detail, setDetail] = useState({
        Content: "",
        CreatedBy: 1,
        CreatedOn: "",
        Id: 0,
        IsDeleted: 0,
        IsVisible: 1,
        ModifiedBy: 1,
        ModifiedOn: "",
        Name: "",
        SiteId: 1,
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        let abortController = new AbortController();
        let mounted = true;
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                setLoader(true);
                let apiUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_IMAGEGALLERYAPI + "/getbyId/" + id;
                const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
                    signal: abortController.signal,
                });
                const json = await response.json();
                const resultPages = json ? json.list : "";
                if (resultPages && resultPages.length > 0) {
                    //debugger;
                    let firstRow = resultPages[0];
                    let isEnabled = false;
                    if (firstRow.IsVisible === 1 || firstRow.IsVisible === true) {
                        isEnabled = true;
                    }

                    let newDetailPage = {
                        Id: firstRow.Id,
                        Name: firstRow.Name,
                        Content: firstRow.Content                                                    
                    };

                    if (mounted) {
                        setDetail(newDetailPage);
                    }

                    let itemRows = [];
                    for (let item of resultPages) {
                        let row = {
                            Id: item.DetailId,
                            ImageSliderId: item.ImageSliderId,
                            ImageName: item.ImageName,                              
                            ImageFullUrl: item.ImageFullUrl,                                                           
                        };
                        if (item.ImageFullUrl) {
                            itemRows.push(row);
                        }
                    }
                    if (itemRows && itemRows.length > 0) {
                        if (mounted) {
                            setList(itemRows);
                        }
                    }
                }
                setLoader(false);
                //abortController = null;
            } catch (err) {
                setLoader(false);
                if (err.name === "AbortError") {
                    // Handling error thrown by aborting request
                }
            }
        };
        fetchData();
        // Side-effect logic...
        return () => {
            // Side-effect cleanup
            mounted = false;
            abortController.abort();
            console.log("unmounting...");
        };
    }, []);

    const [imageCropWidth, setImageCropWidth] = useState(100);
    const [imageCropHeight, setImageCropHeight] = useState(100);

    const [crop, setCrop] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1);
    const [aspect, setAspect] = useState(1);
    const [croppedAreaPixels, setCroppedAreaPixels] = useState(null);
    const [croppedImage, setCroppedImage] = useState(null);
    const [cropSize, setCropSize] = useState({ width: 100, height: 100 });
    const [Image, setImage] = useState("");
    const [rotation, setRotation] = useState(0);
    const [cropShape, setCropShape] = useState("rect");

    const onSaveImage = useCallback(
        async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (validate() < 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            try {
                let filename = "";
                let base64Image = "";
                let blobUrl = "";
                debugger;               
                const cropImage = await getCroppedImg(Image, croppedAreaPixels, rotation);                
                setCroppedImage(cropImage);
                setImage(cropImage);
                base64Image = cropImage ? cropImage.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "") : "";
                const contentType = "image/jpeg";
                if (cropImage) {
                    debugger;                
                    setRow((prevState) => {                        
                        return {
                            ...prevState,                            
                            ["ImageFullUrl"]: cropImage,
                            ["ImageName"]: ImageName ? ImageName : "",
                        };
                    });

                    filename = ImageName ? ImageName : "";                    
                    const settings = {
                        method: "POST",
                        headers: {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            filename: filename,
                            image: base64Image,
                        }),
                    };
                    setLoader(true);
                    let submitUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_DOMAIN + `/uploaddetail`;
                    const responseMain = await fetch(submitUrl, settings);
                    const jsonRes = await responseMain.json();
                    if (jsonRes) {
                        let convertedJson = jsonRes;
                        if (convertedJson) {
                            setLoader(false);
                            const uploadedImageUrl = convertedJson.fullurl; // get saved image url
                            const uploadedImageName = convertedJson.imagename;
                            const uploadedServerPath = convertedJson.serverpath;
                            const uploadurl = convertedJson.url;
                            setImageName(convertedJson.imagename);                         
                            setRow((prevState) => {                                
                                return {
                                    ...prevState,
                                    ["ImageName"]: uploadedImageName,
                                    ["ImageServerPath"]: uploadedServerPath,
                                    ["ImageFullUrl"]: uploadedImageUrl,
                                    ["ImageUrl"]: uploadurl,
                                };
                            });
                            if (uploadedImageUrl) {
                                setIsDisabled(false);
                            }
                            setUModalShow(false);                                                        
                            setDetail((prevState) => {                                
                                return {
                                    ...prevState,
                                    ["Content"]: content,
                                };
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (err) {               
                console.log(err);
                showToast("Error!", "Image couldn't be saved");
            } finally {
            }
        },
        [croppedAreaPixels, rotation]
    );

    const showImageForCrop = useCallback(
        async (e) => {
            debugger;
            let localSrc = e.ImageFullUrl; //e.target.src;
            setImage(localSrc);
            setUModalShow(true);
            setImageName(e.ImageName);
            setCropSize({ width: imageCropWidth ? parseInt(imageCropWidth) : 0, height: imageCropHeight ? parseInt(imageCropHeight) : 0 });
            if (list && list.length > 0) {
                const selectedIndex = list.findIndex((item) => item.Id === e.Id);
                if (selectedIndex > -1) {
                    setRow(list[selectedIndex]);
                }
            }
        },
        [row]
    );

    const singlefileSelectedHandler = async (e) => {
        //debugger;
        e.preventDefault();
        setIsDisabled(true);
        content = "";

        if (!e.target.files || e.target.files.length <= 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (detail && detail.Content) {
            content = detail.Content;
        }
        //let imageList = "";
        const selectedImage = e.target.files[0];
        let imageSizeInMBs = selectedImage.size ? selectedImage.size / 1024 / 1024 : 0;
        if (selectedImage && imageSizeInMBs > 8) {
            setIsDisabled(false);            
            setRow((prevState) => {                
                return {
                    ...prevState,
                    ["ImageName"]: "",
                    ["ImageServerPath"]: "",
                    ["ImageFullUrl"]: "",
                    ["ImageUrl"]: "",
                };
            });
            showToast("Information!", "Image size can't be greater than 8MB.");
            return -1;
        }
        
        const filename =
            selectedImage && selectedImage.name
                ? new Date().valueOf() +
                  "_" +
                  selectedImage.name.replace(/\\/g, "").replace(/ /g, "").replace(/'/g, "").replace(/"/g, "").replace(/`/g, "")
                : "";        
        setUModalShow(false);
        setCropSize({ width: imageCropWidth ? parseInt(imageCropWidth) : 0, height: imageCropHeight ? parseInt(imageCropHeight) : 0 });
        setImageName(filename);
        setUModalShow(true);
        let convertedImageFile = await convertImage(selectedImage);
        setBase64SelectedImage(convertedImageFile);       
    };

    async function convertImage(file) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {           
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let base64 = e.target.result;
                base64 = base64.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "");
                setImage(reader.result);

                resolve(base64);
                //resolve(reader.result);
            };
            reader.onerror = function (error) {
                console.log("Error: ", error);
                reject(error);
            };
        });
    }
    const onAddSide = (e) => {
        //debugger;
        let newImageList = [...list];
        if (row.Id && row.Id > 0) {
            if (newImageList && newImageList.length > 0) {
                const selectedIndex = newImageList.findIndex((item) => item.Id === row.Id);
                if (selectedIndex > -1) {
                    newImageList[selectedIndex] = row;
                }
            }
        } else {
            row.Id = Math.max.apply(
                Math,
                newImageList.map(function (o) {
                    return o.Id + 1;
                })
            );
            if (!row.Id || (row.Id && row.Id === 0) || row.Id === -Infinity) {
                row.Id = 1;
            }
            newImageList.push(row);
        }
        setList(newImageList);
        
    };

    const onCropComplete = useCallback((croppedArea, croppedAreaPixels) => {
        //debugger;
        setCroppedAreaPixels(croppedAreaPixels);
    }, []);

    const onClose = useCallback(() => {
        setCroppedImage(null);
    }, []);

    const onCropperZoomChange = (e) => {
        if (e && e.currentTarget && e.currentTarget.value) {
            let lZoomValue = e.currentTarget.value;
            if (lZoomValue && lZoomValue < 0.4) {
                //setZoom(0.28);
                setZoom(0.4);
            } else if (lZoomValue && lZoomValue > 1) {
                setZoom(1);
            } else {
                setZoom(lZoomValue);
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <Page breadcrumb={breadcrumb} pageName={pageName} fluid>
            <form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={HandleSaveMenu} className="user-form">
                <Card>
                    <Card.Header>
                        <TitleBar title="Edit Gallery" />
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <div className="form-row">                                
                            <div className="form-group col-md-2">
                                <label className="form-label" htmlFor="ImageCropWidth">
                                    Width
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    name="ImageCropWidth"
                                    id="ImageCropWidth"
                                    className={`form-control`}
                                    value={imageCropWidth}
                                    onChange={(e) => setImageCropWidth(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group col-md-2">
                                <label className="form-label" htmlFor="ImageCropWidth">
                                    Height
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    name="ImageCropWidth"
                                    id="ImageCropWidth"
                                    className={`form-control`}
                                    value={imageCropHeight}
                                    onChange={(e) => setImageCropHeight(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </div>                                
                        </div>
                        <SingleGalleryRow
                            data={row}
                            setRow={setRow}
                            onUpload={singlefileSelectedHandler}
                            onAddSide={onAddSide}
                            IsDisabled={IsDisabled}
                        />

                        <ul className="slide-list">
                            {list &&
                                list.map(function (item, i) {
                                    //debugger;
                                    return (
                                        <li key={i}>
                                            <div className="slide-row">
                                                <div className="img-holder">
                                                    <img
                                                        className="thumbnail"
                                                        src={item.ImageFullUrl}
                                                        alt={item.ImageName}
                                                        onClick={() => showImageForCrop(item)}
                                                    />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    );
                                })}
                        </ul>
                    </Card.Body>
                    <Card.Footer>
                        <div className="btn-holder text-right">
                            <Button type="submit" variant="primary" disabled={isSubmitClicked}>
                                Save
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </Card.Footer>
                </Card>
            </form>
            <CenteredPopup
                show={umodalShow}
                onHide={() => setUModalShow(false)}
                title="Crop Image"
                content=""
                closetext="Close"
                savetext="Apply"
                onSaveChanges={onSaveImage}
            >
                <div className="cropimage-container">
                    <div className="cropimage-tools">
                        <span className="cropimage-icons" onClick={(e) => setCropShape("rect")}>
                            <MdOutlineCrop />
                            <span className="cropimage-text">Crop</span>
                        </span>
                        <span className="cropimage-icons" onClick={(e) => setCropShape("round")}>
                            <MdOutlineCircle />
                            <span className="cropimage-text">Circle</span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="crop-container">
                        <Cropper
                            image={Image}
                            crop={crop}                              
                            cropSize={cropSize}
                            cropShape={cropShape}
                            zoom={zoom || 1}
                            showGrid={true}
                            zoomWithScroll={false}
                            objectFit="horizontal-cover"
                            onCropChange={setCrop}
                            onCropComplete={onCropComplete}
                            onZoomChange={onCropperZoomChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-row ic_rangeslider">
                    <div className="form-group col-md-12">
                        <label className="form-label" htmlFor="ZoomBtn">
                            {zoom || 1}
                        </label>
                        <span className="range-slider__wrap">
                            <input
                                id="zoomrangeid"
                                type="range"
                                className="slider range-slider range-slider--light"
                                value={zoom || 1}
                                min={0.4}
                                max={1}
                                step={0.1}
                                aria-labelledby="Zoom"
                                onChange={onCropperZoomChange}
                            />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </CenteredPopup>
        </Page>
    );
}    
export default withRouter(EditImage);
```

Comment: Is the server side working correctly ? have you debugged the source ?